# Gridview delete row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When i click on the delete button it does not call delete function. can anyone help me?

```
protected void GridViewQuestion_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ImageButton lb = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButtonDelete");

                lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
                     "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record " +
                     DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "question") + "')");
            }
        }

        protected void GridViewQuestion_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int questionID = (int)GridViewQuestion.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

            TopicEntity.deleteQuestion(questionID);

            BindGridData();
        }

public bool deleteQuestion(int QuestionID)
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();
            dbCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Question QuestionID=@QuestionID";
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionID", QuestionID);

            bool deleteSuccess = false;

            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                deleteSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
            return deleteSuccess;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your markup look like?  You should have something similar to this for your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDeleted="GridViewQuestion_RowDeleting" />
```

Or, by the method name, you might want to use `OnRowDeleting`:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDeleting="GridViewQuestion_RowDeleting" />
```

**EDIT**:

The error is in your SQL statement.  It should be this:

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Question where QuestionID=@QuestionID";
```

You are missing the `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: i already written these in my gridview. when i click on delete button got prompt a message box. But it didn't delete from database.

Comment: @lixi Ok, so your event handler is actually getting reached.  Your question made it sound like your event didn't fire.  As for deleting data from your database, you'll need to post the code for your `deleteQuestion()` method.  No way to tell what is happening there.

Comment: @lixi Please see my edit.  The issue is in your command text.

Comment: Ok.. i forget to add the WHERE in. But even if i add the Where keywork, it oso not working. And i putting my gridview inside a updatepanel. Will that affect?

Comment: @lixi Put a breakpoint in your `GridViewQuestion_RowDeleting()` method.  You need to figure out if you're actually firing that event.

Comment: @lixi Then your event is not getting triggered.  Please edit your post and put your markup where you're assigning this method as the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the Delete event is not firing on clicking the ImageButton, then you have forgotten to add `CommandName="Delete"` in your ImgaButton's markup. Also please ensure that your GridView *bind* on `Page_Load` does so inside `if(!IsPostBack)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int imageID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string constring = @"Server=User-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Student;Integrated Security=true";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        conn.Open();
        string query="Delete from [student].[dbo].[ImageTable] where ID=" +imageID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.LoadGrid();
        conn.Close();

    }
}
```